# why am getting current position as null

Tags: flutter

I am implementing map in flutter, I want it to show user current location as soon as it get launched, but getting error saying "Null check operator used on a null value" after few second the error disappear and it shows the current user location on a map. Why it first call currentLocation as null and then shows the current user location here are the codes

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class Usermap extends StatefulWidget {
  const Usermap({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _UsermapState createState() => _UsermapState();
}

class _UsermapState extends State<Usermap> {
  LatLng? currentPosition;
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  Set<Marker> markers = {};
  @override
  void initState() {
    getCurrentPosition();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future getCurrentPosition() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    setState(() {
      if (position != null) {
        currentPosition = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
        markers.add(Marker(
            markerId: const MarkerId('12'),
            position: currentPosition!,
            infoWindow: const InfoWindow(title: 'am here')));
      } else {
        print('error');
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return SizedBox(
        height: height,
        width: width,
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              GoogleMap(
                  initialCameraPosition:
                      CameraPosition(target: currentPosition!, zoom: 15),
                  myLocationEnabled: true,
                  myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                  zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                  markers: markers,
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                    setState(() {
                      _controller.complete(controller);
                    });
                  }),
              SafeArea(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ClipOval(
                        child: Material(
                          color: Colors.blue[100], // button color
                          child: InkWell(
                            splashColor: Colors.blue, // inkwell color
                            child: const SizedBox(
                              width: 50,
                              height: 50,
                              child: Icon(Icons.add),
                            ),
                            onTap: () async {
                              final GoogleMapController mapController =
                                  await _controller.future;
                              mapController.animateCamera(
                                CameraUpdate.zoomIn(),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20),
                      ClipOval(
                        child: Material(
                          color: Colors.blue[100], // button color
                          child: InkWell(
                            splashColor: Colors.blue, // inkwell color
                            child: const SizedBox(
                              width: 50,
                              height: 50,
                              child: Icon(Icons.remove),
                            ),
                            onTap: () async {
                              final GoogleMapController mapController =
                                  await _controller.future;
                              mapController.animateCamera(
                                CameraUpdate.zoomIn(),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SafeArea(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
                    child: ClipOval(
                      child: Material(
                        color: Colors.orange[100], // button color
                        child: InkWell(
                          splashColor: Colors.orange, // inkwell color
                          child: const SizedBox(
                            width: 56,
                            height: 56,
                            child: Icon(Icons.my_location),
                          ),
                          onTap: () {},
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you have used a null check operator in your `build` method as such

```
...
CameraPosition(target: currentPosition!, zoom: 15),
...
```

which implies that **currentPosition** is not null for sure, which is not true for the first build of the widget.

In order to fix this, you should either initialize the **currentPosition** variable in **initState()** to some default location, or even better you should check if **currentPosition** is null, and create an appropriate widget as such:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if(currentPosition == null){
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
  else{
    return ... <- your code goes here
  }
```

Comment: thanks you saved my work

Comment: @kajembe if it works, please accepy my answer. I'm happy to help

Comment: have accepted bro thanks very much